# Nginx rewrite any arg name

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, arguments

I am trying to build a rewrite for CDN system which uses arguments to point to the data. All data is stored in the same location so any rewrite needs to wildcard rewrite the $arg_name and then pass the value for the data along. Turning this:

```
http://cdn.example.com/data/?main_loc=datastring
```

into this:

```
http://example.com/datastore/datastring
```

Using a location directive I can fetch the request to /data/, but from there I don't know what the rewrite would need to look like to do a "match any arg name" like main_loc, backup_loc etc. to pass its value as rewrite.
Can I apply regex to match any $arg_name and use the value from that?

```
location ^~ /data/ {
    rewrite ^$arg_(\w*\_\w*)$ http://example.com/datastore/$1;
}
```

Or what would that look like?

Comment: are you sure that your original url is actually looks like this `http://cdn.example.com/data/main_loc?=datastring` ?

Comment: Ups, yes a small typo, sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the arg value with the following map:

```
map $args $arg_value {
    ~=(.*) $1;
}
```

Then redirect to it:

```
location = /data/ {
    return 301 http://example.com/datastore/$arg_value;
}
```

Comment: The problem is main_loc is one of the possible locations and spins up additional ones based on region which could be named anything _loc hence the need for some wildcard or regex in the arg name

Comment: I've updated my answer to ignore the arg name.

Comment: Can I use the $arg_value in a rewrite as well to turn data into datastore or does that only work with a redirect? I'd prefer using a rewrite to reduce problems with browsers caching them.

Comment: You could try, but I don't it would be needed. In fact `return` is prefered over `rewrite` according to [this article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/ "nginx blog post").

Comment: For completeness what would the rewrite look like? (helps me with testing too since main_loc is in the same nginx instance at the moment)

Comment: I did try a rewrite to /datastore/$arg_value; but that does not seem to send it to the /datastore/ location only to /. Is there a special way to rewrite to a location in the same server?

Comment: I avoid rewrite rules, so I am the wrong one to ask. The author of nginx, Igor Sysoev, [explains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWRYbLKsS0I "Presentation by nginx author, Igor Sysoev, @nginxconf 2014") why care should be taken when using rewrite and also regex locations.